# onAppear gets called after the View is rendered in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, struct

I am relatively new to SwiftUI and I am trying to create multiple randomly placed button on the screen using a random number generator and an array to store these random number in order to ensure that I don't render two button at the same place. The problem I am facing is that while I get the random number's displayed, I am unable to update the array in time for the function to check if the number has already been selected.

This is my current solution

**ButtonView**:

```swift
struct ButtonView: View {
    func handleButton() {
        //DO SOMETHING  
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let randX = Int(getRandomX(maxScreenWidth: 350))
        Button(action: handleBubbleButtonClick) {
            Text("Bubble \(randX)")
        }.onAppear {
            print("ADDING : \(randX)")
            CommonAppParameters.shared.plottedXPoints.append(randX)
        }
    }
    
}
```

**Common**

```swift
class CommonAppParameters {
    static let shared = CommonAppParameters()
        var plottedXPoints: [Int] = []
        var plottedYPoints: [Int] = []
    }
    
    func getRandomX(maxScreenWidth: Int) -\> CGFloat {
        let maxWidth = maxScreenWidth
        let plottedXPoints = CommonAppParameters.shared.plottedXPoints
    
        guard maxWidth > 0 else {
            return CGFloat(0)
        }
        
        let highestPoint = maxWidth/2 - 20;
        let lowestPoint = -maxWidth/2 + 20;
        
        let randomNumber: Int = Int.random(in: lowestPoint...highestPoint);
        
        for point in plottedXPoints {
            let range = point-20...point+20
            if (range ~= randomNumber) {
                return getRandomX(maxScreenWidth: maxWidth)
            }
        }
        
        //If I try adding it here, for some reason the application crashes, I would appreciate it if someone could explain why?    
        //CommonAppParameters.shared.plottedXPoints.append(randomNumber)
        return CGFloat(randomNumber)
    }
}
```

**MainView**

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    var body: View {
        VStack {
            ForEach((1...10), id: \.self) { something in 
                ButtonView()    
        }
    }
}
```

Expectation

I wanted the `plottedXPoints` array to fill as the button's were rendered, but what is happening is that the buttons get rendered with different random X points and the array get filled with different ones.

[image: Application UI]

[image: Console UI]

These both should contain the same numbers for this to work properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! There are a lot of things that are working against you in this code. I would start with [Apple's SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) and rework the code from there. A few points, the [X,Y] coordinates should be a data model in their own struct. If you then store these models in a `Set`, you won't have to worry about unique points (though the buttons could overlap). Starting this way will also make it easier for you to build the UI step by step.